# How to find the normal vector of $xyz=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do I find the normal vector of $ xyz=1 $ at $(a, b, c)$?

Is the answer below correct? Because some answers on here are saying that the normal vector is

$$
\Delta F = (f_x,\:f_y,\:-1) 
$$

So wouldn't it be

$$
\left( \frac {1}{x}, \frac {1}{y}, -1 \right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
f(x,y,z)=xyz-1.
$$
Then
$$
(f_x,f_y,f_z)=(yz,zx,xy)=\left(\frac{1}{x},\frac{1}{y},\frac{1}{z}\right),
$$
is perpendicular to the surface $xyz=1$.

Comment: Thanks. Then would the normal vector at (a,b,c) be $\begin{pmatrix}
{1/}{a}\cr
{1/}{b}\cr
{1/}{c}\cr
\end{pmatrix}$?